# Konig's theorem and perfect graphs

Tags: graph-theory, math-history, bipartite-graphs

I want to understand why perfect graphs are so named and why are they relevant.

Consider the following statement from wikipedia's article on [Konig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)).

> A graph is perfect if and only if its complement is perfect, and König's theorem can be seen as equivalent to the statement that the complement of a bipartite graph is perfect.

Does the Konig-Hall theorem characterizing bipartite graphs that have perfect matchings is the reason for calling perfect graphs as perfect? If not what is the origin of this terminology? Secondly what is the importance of the perfect graph theorem. (A graph is perfect iff its complement is too.)

Comment: do you know what the definition of perfect is?

Comment: @SeanEnglish: A perfect graph is one in which for every induced subgraph the clique and chromatic numbers are equal.